# What does "The method is undefined for the type Arrays" mean?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to make a shopping cart program, using only arrays. (Not arraylist)
But, I have errors at my 'addItem' method and it says

- The method addItem(int[], int) is undefined for the type Arrays
- The method addItem(String[], String) is undefined for the type Arrays
- The method addItem(double[], double) is undefined for the type Scanner*
  and I have no idea how to debug this.. can anyone help me with those?
  (I haven't finished all of the menu - switch/case yet. Just want to finish 'Add Item' first)

  import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class A_retail {

  ```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total;
        int quantity;
        String name = null;
        double price = 0;
        String option;


        System.out.println("How many kinds of items do you have in total?");
        total = myinput.nextInt();

        int[] Quantity = new int[total];
        String[] Name = new String[total];
        double[] Price = new double[total];


        for (int i = 0; i<total; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please type the quantity of your item(s) (ex : If you have 2 shirts, please type 2));   
            Quantity[i] = myinput.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please type the name of your item(s)");
            Name[i] = myinput.next();

            System.out.println("Please type the price of your item(s)");
            Price[i] = myinput.nextDouble();            
        }



        System.out.println("Please choose one option below \n1) Add item(s) \n2) Remove item(s) \n3) View Cart \n4) Checkout \n5) Exit");
        option = myinput.next();

        switch(option)
        {
        case "1" , "Add item(s)": 
            System.out.println("How many items do you want to add?");
            int add = myinput.nextInt();

            for(int i=0; i<add; i++)
            {
                System.out.print("Please type the quantity of your item(s)");
                quantity = myinput.nextInt();
                Quantity = Arrays.addItem(Quantity, quantity); //error in addItem


                System.out.print("Please type the name of your item(s)");
                name = myinput.next();
                Name = Arrays.addItem(Name, name); //error in addItem

                System.out.print("Please type the price of your item(s)");
                price = myinput.nextDouble();
                Price = myinput.addItem(Price, price); //error in addItem               
            }

            break;
        }


    }//end item


     public static int[] addItem(int[] array, int item)
       {
               int [] newArray = new int [array.length + 1];
               for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
               {
                       newArray[i] = array[i];
               }
               newArray[newArray.length-1] = item;
               return newArray;
       }//end addItem

     public static String[] addItem(String[] array, String item)
       {
               String [] newArray = new String [array.length + 1];
               for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
               {
                       newArray[i] = array[i];
               }
               newArray[newArray.length-1] = item;
               return newArray;
       }//end addItem


      public static double[] addItem(double[] array, double item)
      {
              double [] newArray = new double [array.length + 1];
              for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
              {
                      newArray[i] = array[i];
              }
              newArray[newArray.length-1] = item;
              return newArray;
      }//end addItem
  ```

  }//end class

Comment: it literally means just that: that method with that signature does not exist in Arrays

Comment: Call them via addItem(..., ...) without Something. in front.

Answer (score 0):

```
Quantity = Arrays.addItem(Quantity, quantity);
```

You are using the addItem method of the Arrays class

```
 Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);

 ...

 Price = myinput.addItem(Price, price);
```

You are using the addItem method of the Scanner class

You are not using the addItem method you declared in class A_retail

try this

```
Quantity = addItem(Quantity, quantity);
Name = addItem(Name, name);
Price = addItem(Price, price);
```